# Swissonic UA-2x2 audio interface with Android 11 on Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite

Tags: samsung, hardware, audio-recording

I want to use a Swissonic UA-2x2 audio interface with my Android 11 on Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite to record guitar with an app called Loopify. However, it does not work if I connect everything. I can manage to capture the guitar signal with another app called n-Track (a kind of DAW for Android).

On my Android smartphone (same Android version) it works with Loopify and the audio interface with no problems - plug and play.

Can I change something about the tablet settings so that it also works with the Loopify app?